# How to format definitions for easy addition in appendix

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got a 200+ page document that I have multiple definitions in. (IE "Automobile
 - means a motorized horse and carriage").

I'd like to have an appendix that I can easily update, that includes all these definitions.  I'm thinking I could format my definitions with "Heading 4", and then create a Table of Contents that only shows Heading 4, that way I can just "refresh table" and the definitions would appear...but I feel that is a bit kludgy and there is a better way to do this.

I've also thought about VBA to search for `- means` and return the paragraph that holds that, but I'd prefer not to use VBA and am thinking surely Word has something I could use to get this accomplished?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: isn't it a similar idea to an index? or maybe you could demonstrate what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could use the [Table of Authority](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-table-of-authorities-ddd126ae-52bc-4299-9558-06dd0e4fe8c0) to do this. I would create a new "Definition" as a Citation Category.  Then it creates a table I can refresh, like a TOC.